# How can I get my bool value out of a future<bool>?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, gorouter

```
static Future<bool> getLoginStatus() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final status = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
    return status;
  }
```

I have this function as a sharedpreference and I need it to return the bool value, how can I do this?

Comment: await that function inside a variable like this: `bool value = await getLoginStatus();`

Answer (score 1):

Use `await` to obtain bool from `Future<bool>`.

```
bool value = await getLoginStatus();
```

Comment: Ive done that, but it might be the context that I am using it in thats the problem.

Comment: So what problem you are facing after doing this?

Comment: I am using GoRouter, and I want to implement this with the redirect. I want to get the bool value out so that I can use it to check if a user is logged in, and if not I want to block them from viewing pages unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

One way of going about this

```
getLoginStatus().then((bool isLoggedIn){
  // you can used isLoggedIn here
});
```

Also,

```
bool isLoggedIn = await getLoginStatus();
// you can used isLoggedIn from here
```

Comment: I still get the result as an instance of future bool.